# jquery animate delaying

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

http://jsfiddle.net/pahnin/rdgbq/16/ look at this fiddle.
In this fiddle the animate function is running late and looking weird also the first time when I click the logo the animate doesn't work

Any suggestion please . .

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found why your code is running slowly. Every time you click the logo div, you are hooking up a new `.click()` event handler.

Try changing your indentation so that the `$('.items').click(function() {` is outside the `$('#logo').click(function() {` block.

http://jsfiddle.net/rdgbq/17/

so your code becomes (just a partial section of your code):

```
$('#logo').click(function() {
    a = 1;
    d = -2;
    $('#container div').each(function() {
        $('#sidebar').hide().animate({
            top: '80%'
        }).removeClass('side');
        if (d > 3.5) {
            d = -2;
        }
        c = d * 10 + "%";
        if ((a - 1) % 3 == 0) {
            b = a * 10 + "%";
        }
        $(this).animate({
            top: b,
            left: c
        });
        a++;
        d += 2;
        $(this).show();
        $(this).corner();
    });
    d = -2;
});
$('.items').click(function() {
    var h = $(this).html();
    $('#sidebar').show().html(h).animate({
        top: '10%'
    }).corner("left").addClass('side');
    $('#container div').each(function() {
        if (d > 3.5) {
            d = -2;
        }
        c = -d * 10 + "%";
        $(this).animate({
            top: '100%',
            left: c
        });
        d += 2;
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

There is some more optimisation that you can do, but this should help!

Comment: sorry that didn't fixed but made a bit more complicated and check the link you have provided its the same with my code

Comment: @pahnin: Sorry about the link (not sure how that was the wrong one). Can you edit your original question with some kind of programming flow? I'm having a hard time determining exactly how things should work (although I get the desired effect). Plus the variables such as `a` and `d` are very hard to work out what they do. Descriptive names are always better.